# Fake screen size with Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, screen-size

So I have a webpage that I want to show in a `WebView`. The problem is that I want to force this webpage to show in desktop mode, which it doesn't do unless it detects a fairly large screen size.

Is there anyway to fake the screen size of a `WebView` so that I can load this webpage in desktop mode?

I have tried adding Javascript into the webpage afterwards but it only seems to enter desktop mode if it detects a large screen size at the beginning of it's loading process.

Comment: Could you explain how your web page detects desktop vs. mobile mode? Is it through a media query in CSS?

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure. It's definitely not the User Agent so I guess it must be a media query? I can't think of many other ways to do it..